# Updating a dataframe by referencing row values and column values without iterating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am rusty with Pandas and Dataframes.

I have one dataframe (named `data`) with two columns (`userid`, `date`).
I have a second dataframe, `incidence_matrix`, where the rows are `userid`s (the same `userid`s in data) and the columns are dates (the same dates in `data`). This is how I construct `incidence_matrix`:

```
columns = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-11-30', freq='M', closed='right')
index = data['USERID']
incidence_matrix = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=columns)
incidence_matrix = incidence_matrix.fillna(0)
```

I am trying to iterate over each (`userid`, `date`) pair in `data`, and using the *values* of each userid and date, update that corresponding cell in `incidence_matrix` to be 1.

In production `data` could be millions of rows. So I'd prefer to not iterate over the data and use a vectorization approach.

How can (or should) the above be done?

I am running into errors when attempting to reference cells by name, for example in my attempt below, the first print statement works but the second print statement doesn't recognize a date value as a label

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():
  print(row['USERID'], row['POSTDATE'])
  print(incidence_matrix.loc[row['USERID']][row['POSTDATE']])
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: sounds like `get_dummies()` ([Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html)) on the data df solves your problem. It won't have every possible date value if that matters to you though. But should be an easy enough adaptation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning: the representation you have chosen is going to be pretty sparse in real life (user visits typically follow a Zipf law), leading to a quite inefficient usage of the memory. You'd be better off representing your incidence as a tall and thin `DataFrame`, for example the output of:

```
data.groupby(['userid', data['date'].dt.to_period('M')]).count()
```

With this caveat out of the way:

```
def add_new_data(data, incidence=None):
    delta_incidence = (
        data
        .groupby(['userid', data['date'].dt.to_period('M')])
        .count()
        .squeeze()
        .unstack('date', fill_value=0)
    )
    if incidence is None:
        return  delta_incidence
    return incidence.combine(delta_incidence, np.add, fill_value=0).astype(int)
```

should do what you want. It re-indexes the previous value of `incidence` (if any) such that the outcome is a new `DataFrame` where the axes are the union of `incidence` and `delta_incidence`.

Here is a toy example, for testing:

```
def gen_data(n):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        dict(
            userid=np.random.choice('bob alice john james sophia'.split(), size=n),
            date=[
                (pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01') + v * pd.Timedelta('365 days')).round('s')
                for v in np.random.uniform(size=n)
            ],
        )
    )

# first time (no previous incidence)
data = gen_data(20)
incidence = add_new_data(data)

# new data arrives
data = gen_data(30)
incidence = add_new_data(data, incidence)
```

Comment: @pierre_d very interesting. thank you. diving into some of the details of this and will post any follow up questions here.